# selenium webbrowser: How to extract several attribute names by iteration?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, attributes, web-crawler

I am trying to **scrape** data (departure times, carrier, price etc.) from a train searching platform `(https://www.thetrainline.com)` and i get a problem for extracting the names of attributes. The HTML for all connection looks like follows and i want to get a list of all carriers, ie. i want to get from the attribute "`data-test-carrier-neme`" the corresponding carrier, here "`trenitalia`".

```
div class="_1moixrt _dtnn7w" tabindex="0"span data-test-carrier-name="trenitalia"
```

For example for the times i just gather the text of attributes by iteration (see Syntax)
Now for the carrier i dont succeed to gather the attribute names. I only get the name of the carrier for the first iteration/first connection but not the following connections.

```
dep_times = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="_1rxwtew "]')
dep_times_list = [x.text for x in dep_times]
```

**#First Approach:** I get the attribute name but only for the first connection

```
carrier1 = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('(//div[@class="_1moixrt _dtnn7w"])[1]/span[1]')

carrier1_list = [x.get_attribute("data-test-carrier-name") for x in carrier1]
```

> Output: ['trenitalia']

**#Second Approach:** I access the attributes of all connection but without getting the name of the attribute:

```
carrier1 = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('(//div[@class="_1moixrt _dtnn7w"])[1]/span[1]')

carrier1_list = [x.get_attribute("data-test-carrier-name") for x in carrier1]
```

> Output: [None, None, None, None, None, None]

Can some one adjust my code in order to solve my issue? Thank you very much for helping!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The xpath which is used in the first approach is returning only one element and thats why the result is showing only the first carrier name. Try this - I just removed the index [1] from your xpath.

```
carrier1 = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('(//div[@class="_1moixrt _dtnn7w"])/span[1]')

carrier1_list = [x.get_attribute("data-test-carrier-name") for x in carrier1]
```

Comment: Hey @Sureshamani! You are absolutely right - with your approach it is perfectly working and i get my desired list of carrier. Thank you soo much for your great advice!!